# "is"-prefixed convenience method confuses CoreData

Tags: objective-c, core-data, methods, nsmanagedobject, objective-c-runtime

I've got an Obj-C app that uses CoreData. The model includes among others the following two entities:

- `Note`
- `QuestionnaireAnswer`

A `Note` has a one-to-one relationship with a `QuestionnaireAnswer` (optional), such that a `Note` can exist on its own, or is associated with a `QuestionnaireAnswer`.

This worked fine for years, until I recently added a convenience method on `Note`:

```
-(BOOL)isQuestionnaireAnswer;
```

All the sudden CoreData started behaving strange; when accessing a `Note`'s `QuestionnaireAnswer` like this, shortly after inserting a new `Note` in my MOC:

```
questionnaireAnswer = [note questionnaireAnswer];
```

the following exception was thrown:

```
-[__NSCFBoolean entity]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

It seemed that CoreData interpreted some type incorrectly. After extensive digging, logging and trial-and-error I found out that simply renaming the convenience method to something like:

```
-(BOOL)wasAddedAsQuestionnaireAnswer;
```

would solve the problem.

***Why?!***

I know that there's a pattern for boolean-type getters to be prefixed with "`is`" followed the actual property name, but it seems here that CoreData on its own tries and infer the type based on available methods or something. I cannot find anyhting in the CoreData documentation indicating reserved names / naming patterns. Also, dumping all methods and properties on `Note` and superclasses didn't reveal any indication of unintended overrides or type mismatches.

**Can anyone shed light on this?**

Comment: I tried to reproduce this but in my test app `isQuestionnaireAnswer` isn't called from `[Note questionnaireAnswer]`. It is called from `-[Note setQuestionnaireAnswer:]` or `[QuestionnaireAnswer setNote:]`. The backtrace shows it's KVO: [Accessor Search Patterns](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/SearchImplementation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000955).

Comment: Thank you @Willeke for investigating it, KVO seems a very plausible cause indeed!